# Who created UWSGI?

Tags: uwsgi

Even if I will be banned after posting this question! I HAVE to say that people considering error message such as `[emperor] unloyal bad behaving vassal found: web2py.ini throttling it...` as something informative and at the same time targeting their software to enterprise, should not have access to keyboard!

As it not allows us to work!!!

*Our civilization depends critically on software, and we have a dangerously low degree of professionalism in the computer fields

 - Bjarne Stroustrup*

Comment: what's unprofessional about it? if that's unprofessional, then surely using a little green robot as the mascot for an OS is unprofessional as well.

Comment: When program not behaves as expected it should be understandable why! Software is a vassal by him self and all prerequisites should be taken to avoid situations when it stills control and puts users to situation when they should become a developers and start rewriting source codes to understand the reason of the issue. Usage of _perror(), errno_ is a minimal requirements that should be satisfied before accessing keyboard.

Comment: and reading the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) should be mandatory before you start posting off-topic non-questions whining about things we have absolutely no involvement or control over.

Comment: This messages should be taken by Blizzard for the future Warcraft releases!

Comment: Yeah, yeah. I believe you read it.

Comment: Try to configure web2py under uwsgi and NGINX at your free time. You will understand me.

Comment: so we've gone to complaining about C coding styles to giving design advice to Blizzard? I'm sure they'll be all over this instantly, because they've got nothing better to do than watch forums for  critiques of C coding styles.

Answer (score 5):

Here i am, the guilty one that should never touch a keyboard :) Frankly speaking the idea that nerd culture (in the IT area) can be considered unprofessional, scares me a lot. I (badly, obviously) do this work because i am a nerd, because i like sci-fi, game and i am (me and my company) so stupid and unprofessional to release for free tons of line of codes, in additional to hours of free support given to other companies and people. The funny thing is that you could have joined an irc channel or a mailing-list, or simply post a standard request to stack overflow, and very probably dozens of people would have helped you.

By the way, here are some note about loyalty and throttling (nothing too much in deep but should be a good start):

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Emperor.html#loyalty

live long and prosper

Comment: Not tons of line of code and thousand of hours spent for support unfortunately don't make me reconsider that error message as something useful. And definitely I don't want to let this discussion grow.  Just dry facts, to start troubleshooting a permissions issue I don't think need to come here? to go to irc? to write emails to community? Something wrong here. If, to understand functions in C people needed to go to forums I don't think any software were exist at all. Think about it. STDOUT is the only way for software to speak. We love it and need it working. Help us. Thanks.

Comment: I have no interest in convincing you that the error is good (or not), we are talking about a software of thousand lines of code, there are gazillion of parts that can be better. I was only trying to remembering you that this is open source, if you do not like something you can propose a change, ask for help, pay for ad-hoc support or use something different. Insulting people that gave you something for free does not look to me a winning or civil approach.

Comment: Once again. Thank you. My complaining was excessive. I'm sorry about that. No one against humor! But, just to note that writing for open source it is an opportunity for all of us to learn and to create. Fortunately decades of community experience achieved standards and best practices for example [https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/]. In my opinion, writing software requires responsibility, and informative error message it is definitely part of it. You know, it is just a user feedback trying to troubleshoot software.